# javascript, somatória de Label

Tags: javascript

Tenho em uma tabela, vários label
ex:

```
<td style="width:10%"><label id="PrecoProd_3" class="negrito">R$ 1.502,25</label></td>
```

Existem várias linhas com esse tipo, mudando apenas o id

Gostaria de colocar embaixo, em um determinado lugar da página um `<label></label>` com a somatória total

Poderia fazer em jquery, javascript puro, qualquer jeito, porém não tenho conseguido isolar os campos, já que não sei os ID (poderá ter várias linhas, então não posso me referenciar pelo id do label (Creio)

tentei fazer assim

```
 function id(el) {
        return document.getElementById(el);
    }
    function somaLabel() {
        //Produtos - é o ID da tabela,
        var inputs = id('Produtos').getElementsByTagName('label');

        var soma = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            soma += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
        }
        alert(soma);
        //id('resultado').value = soma;
    }
```

o alert esta dando NAN
alert só para teste, porque tentei fazer no label final.
Exemplo da aplicação:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/dorathoto/3xDgX/

Comment: Os seus valores têm virgulas às vezes e pontos noutras. Dá para corrigir esses valores ou você tem de trabalhar com eles como estão?

Comment: acho que da para padronizar...preciso só corrigir os outros js, mas da sim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro está na linha

> soma += parseInt(inputs[i].value);

O elemento `label` não tem o atributo `value`, do jeito que você está esperando.

Para isso, você precisa pegar o *texto* do `label`, que pelo `DOM`, é seu primeiro filho.

Assim:

```
soma += parseFloat(inputs[i].firstChild.nodeValue.substr(3).replace(/\./g, "").replace(/,/g, ".")));
```

- O `substr` é para pular o início da sua string `"R$ "`
- Utilizei `parseFloat` por causa das casas decimais
- Os `replace` são para remover o separador de milhar (`"."`) e então substituir o separador decimal `","` por `"."`, de modo que o `parseFloat` possa funcionar corretamente

Além disso, depois de ler o fiddle por completo, tinha um erro na função de conversão para moeda: faltava substituir o `"."` gerado pelo método `toFixed` para `","`, além de corrigir a expressão regular que acrescenta o separador de milhar. O fiddle completo está [aqui](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3xDgX/10/).

O código final, já corrigido, da função em questão é esse mostrado abaixo:

```
function formatDinheiro(n, currency) {
    //às vezes n vem como NaN, quando o usuário deixa o campo em branco
    if (isNaN(n))
        n = 0;
    //converte n para string com 2 casas decimais
    var x = (currency + " " + n.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ",")).split(","),
        x1 = x[0],
        x2 = ((x.length > 1) ? "," + x[1] : ""),
        rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    //acrescenta um separador de milhar a cada 3 dígitos
    while (rgx.test(x1))
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Outro erro, é que ao fazer:

> var inputs = id('Produtos').getElementsByTagName('label');

O `label` com o subtotal também é retornado no array, assim, seu valor entrava na soma novamente. O código corrigido dessa função é esse mostrado abaixo:

```
function somaLabelProduto() {
    var inputs = id("Produto").getElementsByTagName('label');

    var soma = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].id != "sub_total_0")
            soma += parseFloat(inputs[i].firstChild.nodeValue.substr(3).replace(/\./g, "").replace(/,/g, "."));
    }

    document.getElementById('sub_total_0').innerHTML = formatDinheiro(soma, "R$");
}
```

Comment: fiz sua mudança mas não deu certo, acho que não entendi.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/dorathoto/3xDgX/1/

Comment: Oi @Dorathoto! Fiz uma edição à resposta. Veja o último potno que adicionei ao final...

Comment: Oi de novo, @Dorathoto! Seu exemplo do fiddle não funciona, porque tem mais erros, além desse que você comentou...

Comment: Pronto, @Dorathoto! Arrumei seu código, dá uma olhada como ficou o fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/3xDgX/2/  O principal erro era onde a função `soma` estava sendo chamada.

Comment: showwwww, agora sim.. perfeito, mágico..rs
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dorathoto/3xDgX/4/
algumas coisas, da NAN mas ficou bom.

Comment: @Dorathoto O que está resultando em `NaN` pode ser algum problema de conversão (string errada), string em branco, ou algum `undefined`. Contudo, reparei nesse seu novo fiddle que a função `somaLabel` voltou para dentro de `MudaLabeL`. Isso está certo? Outra coisa, é que sua função `SomaTotal` está errada: ela está concatenando strings (falta colocar `parseFloat` em cada termo `document.getEle... nodeValue.substr(3)` antes de somar)

Comment: Mudei para dentro, pois ao alterar o preço ela deve ser novamente recalculada, como não sabia como fazer uma para cada tabela, dupliquei a function que somava..MudalLabelA e MudaLabelB :(  http://fiddle.jshell.net/dorathoto/3xDgX/5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14607/discussion-between-dorathoto-and-carlosrafaelgn).

Comment: mesmo no seu link ele não soma os label, ele apenas concatena..tentei mudar e ainda não funcionou
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dorathoto/3xDgX/6/

Comment: @Dorathoto Estou no chat...

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14607/discussion-between-dorathoto-and-carlosrafaelgn