# Como mudar uma variável texto para valor número?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cast

Tenho esse segmento de código, gostaria que alguém me ajudasse em transformar  a variável `P` (na qual pega o atributo 'valor' ) e transformar ele em valor número para a soma.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {         
    $('.pizzadisponivel').click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('pizzaselecionada');
        var P = $('label').attr('value');
        Total+= P; 
        $("#teste").html('R$' + Total);
        alert(Total)
    });
    var Total = 0;      
});
```

Comment: Se colocar a parte do HTML relevante fica mais facil

Comment: Possível duplicata de [jQuery não soma "+"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87787/jquery-n%c3%a3o-soma)

Answer (score 10):

Eu gosto da simplicidade do [`+` unário](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator):

```
Total += +P;
// Variáveis começam com minúsculas,
// o ideal seria: total += +p;
```

Comment: Porque o + na frente do 'p'? Primeira que vejo ele sendo usando assim @bfvaretto.

Comment: É um operador unário (só tem um operando), que converte para o tipo Number.

Answer (score 3):

Use `parseFloat`, pois o `parseInt` irá converter para inteiros e assim irá perder os centavos do valor, deve ficar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {         
    $('.pizzadisponivel').click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('pizzaselecionada');
        var P = $('label').attr('value');
        Total += parseFloat(P); 
        $("#teste").html('R$' + Total);
        alert(Total)
    });
    var Total = 0;      
});
```

Se precisar de precisão use `.toFixed(2);`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {         
    $('.pizzadisponivel').click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('pizzaselecionada');
        var P = $('label').attr('value');
        Total += parseFloat(P).toFixed(2); 
        $("#teste").html('R$' + Total);
        alert(Total)
    });
    var Total = 0;      
});
```

Se precisar de um calculo fazer um parse de um valor formatado com virgulas e separadores decimais use esta resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16308/3635

Answer (score 2):

Basta utilizar o [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) na variável.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {         
    $('.pizzadisponivel').click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('pizzaselecionada');
        var P = parseInt($('label').attr('value'));//Mudança aqui
        Total+= P; 
        $("#teste").html('R$' + Total);
        alert(Total)
    });
    var Total = 0;      
});
```

Ou se for `double`/`float`, [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)